# How can we find right resonant frequency of a structure?

Tags: atomic-physics, frequency, resonance, vibrations

Structures have infinite DOFs, so it possess infinite mode shapes. How can we find out the right resonant frequency out of the infinite resonant frequencies so that we can save our structure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Save your structure from what? From earthquakes? From wind-induced oscillations? From [Nikola Tesla?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla%27s_oscillator#%22Earthquake%22_claims)

Answer (score 0):

A structure may have infinite mode shapes but in general the higher the frequency the less will be the response to the applied vibration (e.g. from an earthquake). A model of a structure can be made using software, applying all the relevant properties, support conditions, loads and masses. The software builds a structure stiffness matrix and a mass matrix, and the modal frequencies are related to the eigenvalues of the mass matrix. The number of modes can be specified and any higher modes will not be considered. These modes will include oscillations in different principal directions.

The earthquake is normally simulated by inputting a response spectrum, which in general specifies progressively lower amplitudes for higher frequencies.